# Image has decreased resolution when I try to fit or adjust the image png to Iframe in popup? (folium)

Tags: python, html, iframe, folium

I am trying to adjust the image size with Iframe and popup in folium with python, using the following code:

```py
encoded = base64.b64encode(open('mlosvolcanes.png', 'rb').read()).decode()
html = '''<img style="width:100%; height:100%;" src="data:image/png;base64,{}">'''.format
iframe = folium.IFrame(html(encoded), width=360, height=210)
popup = folium.Popup(iframe)      
folium.Marker([-39.47108999, -71.85406208],
                  popup=popup,
                  tooltip=tooltip,
                  icon=logoIcon2).add_to(m)
```

however the result shows me the image in very low resolution comparing the real image and the result, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Please any idea how can I get a better result??

Comment: Have tried tweeking width and heigh iframe = folium.IFrame(html(encoded), `width`=360, `height`=210) ?

Comment: @mplungjan  do you mean oposite values like this:  iframe = folium.IFrame(html(encoded), width=210, height=360 ?? anyway I modifed these values in many differents ways and still doenst work

Comment: no I mean increasing it

Comment: yes I try ! and  doesnt recover the resolution

Comment: actually when you increase those values just the frame and text is bigger but the resolution continue with the same resolution

Comment: @CristianAlvarezOcares You mean Epsi95

Comment: yes @Epsi95 , sorry